# Restoring Windows 10 System Image to RAID

Tags: windows-10, raid, disk-image, system-recovery

I currently have a Windows 10 instance installed on a RAID) that was configured through the BIOS of my PC. I am trying to to re-image this drive from a backup of that was taken last night and stored on a separate drive. I thought that this was going to be a simple task but when attempting to use the Windows `Advanced Startup > Troubleshoot > System Image Recovery` I receive the following error as soon as it tries to start:

> An internal error occurred. The following information might help you resolve the error:
>
> The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

Any Idea on what might be causing this error? And How might I be able to fix it?

After doing some investigating in the `Command Prompt` and `Diskpart` it appears that the RAID is not being recognized by the `Windows Advance Start Up`.

When running `Diskpart> List Volume` from the OS the following volumes are listed:

> Volume 0 - D [Backup] (Drive 0)
>
> Volume 1 - C [Boot] (Drive 1)
>
> Volume 2 -   [Recovery] (Drive 1)

When running `Diskpart> List Volume`from the start up tool I get the following instead:

> Volume 0 - D [Backup] (Drive 0)

I tried loading the drivers for Intel RST from the motherboard driver disc via the command prompt but I am not having any luck loading them. The drivers on the disk are an `.exe` which when run says that it is incompatible with the current version of Windows.

Comment: To get it to see your RAID try this:  Head to Intel, get the [Intel RST "F6 driver"](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26361/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-RAID-Driver), and then load that during the Windows Image Recovery wizard by using [the "Install drivers" button](https://tr4.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2016/02/12/2be2aade-f078-4ebf-822e-8bc2d14a48d2/resize/770x/7df025ff9de0625eeb255027f3422d51/fig-k-2-8cropt.jpg).

Comment: Is the `Windows Image Recovery Wizard` the same tool as `Advanced Start Up > Troubleshooting > System Image Recovery`? If so that took errors as soon as I open it. I can't even get to the screen to install drivers.